# \index command adding spaces after underscores

Tags: pdftex, indexing

I am writing a document with an index of commands that may contain an underscore symbol.
Thus, I use entries like:

```
\index{a\_b}
```

However, the .idx file contains code of the form:

```
\indexentry{a\_ b}{23}
```

Of course, the resulting document reads "a_ b", which is obviously not what I want. Is there a way to avoid this behavior ? Thanks !

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{multind}
\newcommand{\dcommand}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{commands}{\texttt{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\dcommand{foo\_bar}
\dcommand{bar\_foo}
\printindex{commands}{Commands index}
\end{document}
```

[sorry for the time taken to edit, I am working on several projects including some very urgent ones]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This doesn't happen in my experiment; can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: This post hasn't improved since the question was asked :-(

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a package made for LaTeX 2.09 and unmaintained since 1991?

Answer (score 1):

The `multind` package is made for LaTeX 2.09 and has been unmaintained since 1991.

You can get the same effect (and much more) with `imakeidx` and just small changes.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name=commands,title=Commands index]

\newcommand{\dcommand}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index[commands]{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\dcommand{foo\_bar}
\dcommand{bar\_foo}

\printindex[commands]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist in using `multind`, fix the definition of `\@wrindex` by using `\protected@xdef` instead of `\xdef`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multind}

\makeatletter
\def\@wrindex#1#2{\let\thepage\relax
   \protected@xdef\@gtempa{\@ifundefined{#1@idxfile}{}{\expandafter
      \write\csname #1@idxfile\endcsname{\string
      \indexentry{#2}{\thepage}}}}\endgroup\@gtempa
   \if@nobreak \ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi\@esphack}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\dcommand}[1]{\texttt{#1}\index{commands}{\texttt{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\dcommand{foo\_bar}
\dcommand{bar\_foo}
\printindex{commands}{Commands index}
\end{document}
```